# why does image hyperlink has no border in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera

Tags: html, browser

Is there any reason why the current browsers did not support an image hyperlink with a border.

I noticed before that by default it should have a border.

Comment: This is a speculative question, not a practical programming question. Hence off-topic. Besides, the “should” part is wrong; it was never a requirement, just what browsers did (and many people complained about). It would be constructive to ask (though with rather trivial answers) how you can ask browsers to show a border or to not show a border.

Answer (score 1):

It does support:

```css
img {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: block;
}
a {
  border: 3px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</a>

<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" type="submit" />
```